# openmpi ignored error: mca interface is not recognized

Tags: macos, fortran, mpi, gfortran, openmpi

This morning I upgraded my gfortran (from 4.7 to 6.1.0) and OpenMPI (from 1.10 to 2.0.1) compilers. I wrote this simple program:

```
program main                                                                                             
    use mpi_f08                                                                                          
    implicit none                                                                                        
    integer :: ierror                                                                                    

    call mpi_init(ierror)                                                                                
    call mpi_finalize(ierror)                                                                            
end program main
```

When I compile directly (no mpirun, just `./a.out`), I get the following messages (they're not really errors since the program runs as expected):

```
[username:79762] mca_base_component_repository_open: unable to open mca_grpcomm_bad: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_grpcomm_bad.so, 9): Symbol not found: _orte_grpcomm_base_modex
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_grpcomm_bad.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_grpcomm_bad.so (ignored)
[username:79761] mca_base_component_repository_open: unable to open mca_grpcomm_bad: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_grpcomm_bad.so, 9): Symbol not found: _orte_grpcomm_base_modex
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_grpcomm_bad.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_grpcomm_bad.so (ignored)
[username:79761] mca_base_component_repository_open: unable to open mca_pml_bfo: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_bfo.so, 9): Symbol not found: _ompi_free_list_item_t_class
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_bfo.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_bfo.so (ignored)
[username:79761] mca_base_component_repository_open: coll "/usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_hierarch" uses an MCA interface that is not recognized (component MCA v2.0.0 != supported MCA v2.1.0) -- ignored
[username:79761] mca_base_component_repository_open: unable to open mca_coll_ml: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_ml.so, 9): Symbol not found: _mca_bcol_base_components_in_use
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_ml.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_coll_ml.so (ignored)
```

I remember getting similar warnings when I was compiling my code with openmpi and running it with mpich's or intel's version of mpirun. This is clearly not the case now but I thought I'd mention it.

Any idea what causes these warnings?

**Edit:**

To make sure my runtime OpenMPI libraries was indeed 2.0.1, I added this line of code to the one shown above:

```
print'(3(A,I1))', "OpenMPI version = ", OMPI_MAJOR_VERSION, ".", OMPI_MINOR_VERSION, ".",& 
  8                       OMPI_RELEASE_VERSION
```

which gave the following output:

```
OpenMPI version = 2.0.1
```

Following VladimirF's advice, I ran `mpirun -v` which outputted the following:

```
 [username:02210] mca_base_component_repository_open: unable to open mca_grpcomm_bad: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_grpcomm_bad.so, 9): Symbol not found: _orte_grpcomm_base_modex
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_grpcomm_bad.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_grpcomm_bad.so (ignored)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
No executable was specified on the mpirun command line.

Aborting.
```

Also, `mpirun --version` returns: `mpirun (Open MPI) 2.0.1`

Comment: @VladimirF No i was not aware I had to. I thought that went along openMPI. If the MPI library was incompatible with openMPI, wouldn't it have come up during the installation? I did some quick searches online but only links to downloading/installing openMPI come up.

Comment: MPI is a standard. OpenMPI the actual library mado according to that standard. But if you first updated GCC and then installed OpenMPI you should be fine. Next time please report the MPI library type and version, not *"mpif90 version"*.

Comment: @VladimirF I re-installed OpenMPI version 2.0.1 just to make sure it was based on the correct GCC version, but the warnings persist

Comment: Yes, you should be fine, it wouldn't compile at all if it was for the old version.

Comment: But, are you sure your mpirun and the runtime openmpi libraries are also from the new 2.1 version?

Comment: @VladimirF Please see edit. And I'm running the executable directly, without mpirun. Also, running with mpirun yields to the same warning

Comment: The print does not test the mpirun version, it is filled in at the compile time! The libraries are also necessary when running directly. Just test `mpirun -v`.

Comment: @VladimirF I left home so Ill get back to you tomorrow. But i was running the executable directly as ./a.out on purpose because i thought that if the warning persisted, it must not be related to mpirun at all.

Comment: That does not matter.

Comment: @Vladimir Please see edit. And thank you for your help/patience

Comment: @VladimirF Do you have a clue of what the issue might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out the problem thanks to Gilles Gouaillardet's help on the OpenMPI forums.

**Problem:**

I installed the newer version 2.0.1 without uninstalling 1.10. Since I installed it at the same location, some mca files were overwritten while others have been removed or renamed in the newer version and were therefore still present in the directory. In the end, these module files were not recognised by version 2.0.1, resulting in the above warnings.

**Solution:**

1. Remove all the pluging files: `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/openmpi`
2. Reinstall Openmpi: `make install`

Comment: I was suspecting something like that.