# MPI_Bcast non-root nodes not receiving all data

Tags: fortran, mpi

So, I'm currently writing a small scale code that does output using CGNS and adaptive mesh refinement (AMR) with Amrex.  This is all being done with Fortran 95, though CGNS is C with Fortran interfaces and Amrex is C++ with Fortran interfaces (those are not in the sample code).  I'm using OpenMPI 1.10.7.

This will eventually go into a full CFD code, but I wanted to test it small scale to work the bugs out before putting in the larger code.  The program below seems to works every time, but it was originally a subroutine that did not.

I'm having an issue where not all of the data from MPI_Bcast is being received by every process... sometimes.  I can hit execute on the same code, twice in a row and sometimes is bombs out (segfault from CGNS elsewhere in the code, and sometimes it works.  As far as I can tell, the program bombs when not all of the data from MPI_Bcast is received in time to start work elsewhere.  Despite MPI_wait and MPI_barrier, the writes at the bottom in the subroutine will spit out junk on lvl=1 for the last six indices of all the arrays.  Printing information to the screen seems to help, but more processors seem to lower the likelihood of the code working.

I've currently got it as MPI_ibcast with an MPI_wait, but I've also tried MPI_Bcast with MPI_barriers after. Changing the communicator from one defined by Amrex to MPI_COMM_WORLD doesn't help.

...

```
program so_bcast
!
!
!
!
use mpi
implicit none
  integer :: lvl,i,a,b,c,ier,state(MPI_STATUS_SIZE),d
  integer :: n_elems,req,counter,tag,flavor
  integer :: stat(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
  integer :: self,nprocs

type :: box_zones
  integer,allocatable :: lower(:,:),higher(:,:),little_zones(:)
  double precision,allocatable :: lo_corner(:,:),hi_corner(:,:)
  integer :: big_zones
  integer,allocatable :: zone_start(:),zone_end(:)
end type

type(box_zones),allocatable :: zone_storage(:)

call MPI_INIT(ier)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,nprocs,ier)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,self,ier)

lvl = 1
! Allocate everything, this is done elsewhere in the actual code, but done here
! for simplification reasons
allocate(zone_storage(0:lvl))
zone_storage(0)%big_zones = 4
zone_storage(1)%big_zones = 20
do i = 0,lvl
  allocate(zone_storage(i)%lower(3,zone_storage(i)%big_zones))
  allocate(zone_storage(i)%higher(3,zone_storage(i)%big_zones))
  allocate(zone_storage(i)%lo_corner(3,zone_storage(i)%big_zones))
  allocate(zone_storage(i)%hi_corner(3,zone_storage(i)%big_zones))
  zone_storage(i)%lower = self
  zone_storage(i)%higher = self*2+1
  zone_storage(i)%lo_corner = self*1.0D0
  zone_storage(i)%hi_corner = self*1.0D0+1.0D0

  allocate(zone_storage(i)%zone_start(0:nprocs-1))
  allocate(zone_storage(i)%zone_end(0:nprocs-1))
  zone_storage(i)%zone_start(self) = zone_storage(i)%big_zones/nprocs*self+1
  zone_storage(i)%zone_end(self) = zone_storage(i)%zone_start(self)+zone_storage(i)%big_zones/nprocs-1
  if (zone_storage(i)%zone_end(self)>zone_storage(i)%big_zones) zone_storage(i)%zone_end(self) = zone_storage(i)%big_zones
end do

do i = 0,lvl
write(*,*) 'lower check 0',self,'lower',zone_storage(i)%lower
write(*,*) 'higher check 0',self,'high',zone_storage(i)%higher
write(*,*) 'lo_corner check 0',self,'lo_corner',zone_storage(i)%lo_corner
write(*,*) 'hi_corner check 0',self,'hi_corner',zone_storage(i)%hi_corner
write(*,*) 'big_zones check 0',self,'big_zones',zone_storage(i)%big_zones
write(*,*) 'zone start/end 0',self,'lvl',i,zone_storage(i)%zone_start,zone_storage(i)%zone_end
end do

!
! Agglomerate the appropriate data to processor 0 using non-blocking receives
! and blocking sends
!
do i = 0,lvl
  do a = 0,nprocs-1
    call mpi_bcast(zone_storage(i)%zone_start(a),1,&
      MPI_INT,a,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ier)
    call mpi_bcast(zone_storage(i)%zone_end(a),1,&
      MPI_INT,a,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ier)
  end do
end do

call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ier)

counter = 0
do i = 0,lvl
  n_elems = 3*zone_storage(i)%big_zones
  write(*,*) 'number of elements',n_elems
  if (self == 0) then
    do a = 1,nprocs-1
      do c = zone_storage(i)%zone_start(a),zone_storage(i)%zone_end(a)
        tag = c*100000+a*1000+1!+d*10
        call mpi_irecv(zone_storage(i)%lower(1:3,c),3,MPI_INT,a,&
          tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,req,ier)
        tag = tag + 1
        call mpi_irecv(zone_storage(i)%higher(1:3,c),3,MPI_INT,a,&
          tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,req,ier)
        tag = tag +1
        call mpi_irecv(zone_storage(i)%lo_corner(1:3,c),3,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,a,&
          tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,req,ier)
        tag = tag +1
        call mpi_irecv(zone_storage(i)%hi_corner(1:3,c),3,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,a,&
          tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,req,ier)
      end do
    end do
  else
    do b = zone_storage(i)%zone_start(self),zone_storage(i)%zone_end(self)
      tag = b*100000+self*1000+1!+d*10
      call mpi_send(zone_storage(i)%lower(1:3,b),3,MPI_INT,0,&
        tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ier)
      tag = tag + 1
      call mpi_send(zone_storage(i)%higher(1:3,b),3,MPI_INT,0,&
        tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ier)
      tag = tag + 1
      call mpi_send(zone_storage(i)%lo_corner(1:3,b),3,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,&
        tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ier)
      tag = tag +1
      call mpi_send(zone_storage(i)%hi_corner(1:3,b),3,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,&
        tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ier)
    end do
  end if
end do
write(*,*) 'spack'
!
call mpi_barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ier)

do i = 0,lvl
write(*,*) 'lower check 1',self,'lower',zone_storage(i)%lower
write(*,*) 'higher check 1',self,'high',zone_storage(i)%higher
write(*,*) 'lo_corner check 1',self,'lo_corner',zone_storage(i)%lo_corner
write(*,*) 'hi_corner check 1',self,'hi_corner',zone_storage(i)%hi_corner
write(*,*) 'big_zones check 1',self,'big_zones',zone_storage(i)%big_zones
write(*,*) 'zone start/end 1',self,'lvl',i,zone_storage(i)%zone_start,zone_storage(i)%zone_end
end do
!
! Send all the data out to all the processors
!
do i = 0,lvl
  n_elems = 3*zone_storage(i)%big_zones

  req = 1
  call mpi_ibcast(zone_storage(i)%lower,n_elems,MPI_INT,&
    0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,req,ier)
  call mpi_wait(req,stat,ier)
  write(*,*) 'spiffy'
  req = 2
  call mpi_ibcast(zone_storage(i)%higher,n_elems,MPI_INT,&
    0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,req,ier)
  call mpi_wait(req,stat,ier)
  req = 3
  call mpi_ibcast(zone_storage(i)%lo_corner,n_elems,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,&
    0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,req,ier)
  call mpi_wait(req,stat,ier)
  req = 4
  call mpi_ibcast(zone_storage(i)%hi_corner,n_elems,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,&
    0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,req,ier)
  call mpi_wait(req,stat,ier)

  call mpi_barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ier)
end do

write(*,*) 'lower check 2',self,'lower',zone_storage(lvl)%lower
write(*,*) 'higher check 2',self,'high',zone_storage(lvl)%higher
write(*,*) 'lo_corner check ',self,'lo_corner',zone_storage(lvl)%lo_corner
write(*,*) 'hi_corner check ',self,'hi_corner',zone_storage(lvl)%hi_corner
write(*,*) 'big_zones check ',self,'big_zones',zone_storage(lvl)%big_zones

call MPI_FINALIZE(ier)
end program
```

...

As I said, this code works, but the larger version does not always work.  OpenMPI throws several warnings akin to this:

> mca: base: component_find: ess "mca_ess_pmi" uses an MCA interface that is not recognized (component MCA v2.1.0 != supported MCA v2.0.0) -- ignored

> mca: base: component_find: grpcomm "mca_grpcomm_direct" uses an MCA interface that is not recognized (component MCA v2.1.0 != supported MCA v2.0.0) -- ignored

> mca: base: component_find: rcache "mca_rcache_grdma" uses an MCA interface that is not recognized (component MCA v2.1.0 != supported MCA v2.0.0) -- ignored

etc. etc. But the program can still complete even with those warnings.

-Is there a way to ensure that MPI_bcast has emptied its buffer into the correct region of memory before moving on?  It seems to miss this sometimes.

-Is there a different/better method to distribute the data? The sizes have to be able to vary unlike the test program.

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41380194/openmpi-ignored-error-mca-interface-is-not-recognized of any help?

Comment: Also where are the waits for the mpi_irecv's?

Comment: @IanBush Yes, I was just unsure if the warnings were related to the issues.  I'm going to update OpenMPI (or have my IT guys do it since I'm paranoid of screwing it up).  With respect to the mpi_irecv's, I have them paired with blocking mpi_sends and an mpi_barrier afterward so it should all work.  I may I try a wait or a blocking mpi_recv though.

Comment: Please trim down your code to a [mcve] and clearly describe what the problem is and how to reproduce it. You might be able to replace `for() MPI_Bcast()` with a single `MPI_Allgather()` (or `MPI_Allgatherv()` is needed)

Comment: @LordOfBunnies You MUST have a corresponding wait for all non blocking communications. A barrier or corresponding blocking call is NOT enough. Certain MPI implementation have only done the communication in the wait, so no wait, no communication!

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward answer was to use MPI_allgatherv.  As little as I wanted to mess with displacements, it was the best setup to share the information and reduce overall code length.

I believe a MPI_waitall solution would work too, as the data was not being fully received before being broadcast.